# I'd like to code in one-line. List comprehension

Tags: python

```
def vector_size_check(*vector_variables):
    for i in range(len(vector_variables) - 1):
        if len(vector_variables[i]) == len(vector_variables [i + 1]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(vector_size_check([1, 2, 3], [4, 2], [1, 5, 6]))
```

I want to express above code in one line(list comprehension).

Comment: This code almost certainly doesn't do what you want, since you *always* return in the first iteration. Before thinking about rewriting it you should fix it so it actually works.

Comment: Probably your `else` shouldn't be indented?

Comment: As it stands you could use `next()` with a generator expression, but you might actually want `any()` / `all()`

Comment: Do you want to check whether _all_ the vectors have the same length, or which pairs of consecutive vectors have the same length? I.e., return one boolean or a list of booleans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you want to check whether all iterables have the same length:

```
def vector_size_check(*vector_variables):
    return all(len(x) == len(vector_variables[0]) for x in vector_variables)
```

But personally I'd advocate for a solution that is easier to understand even if it has more lines of code.

Comment: define `len(vector_variables[0])` first to save re-computing

Comment: I guess generally you are right but OP explicitly asked for a single line. Also I think in most cases these "micro optimizations" are unneeded, in most of the cases you have small lists anyway, and if you have big data there is a good chance that `__len__` is overriden to cache anyway (e.g. numpy arrays).

Comment: There is never a need to write a single line in python, you should ignore such requests (otherwise write a lambda function). Your other points I agree :) although I don't know without checking the caching rules

Comment: I really appreciate it. I did not know you would answer that soon. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A very concise way of coding it:

```
def vector_size_check(*vector_variables):
    return len(set(map(len,vector_variables)))==1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i meant!

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what the code is supposed to do. Since you ask for a list comprehention, I assume the result should be a list, containing true/false according to whether each pair of consecutive elements have the same length. For this, you can use the `zip(lst, lst[1:])` recipe to iterate those pairs:

```
def vector_size_check(*vs):
    return [len(a) == len(b) for a, b in zip(vs, vs[1:])]

>>> print(vector_size_check([1, 2, 3], [4, 2], [1, 5, 6]))
[False, False]
>>> print(vector_size_check([1, 2, 3], [4, 2], [1,2], [1, 5, 6], [5,6,7]))
[False, True, False, True]
```